# How to use one GCP load balancer for two subdomains?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, google-cloud-load-balancer

I want to create a LAMP site that also has a separate bucket on a subdomain. Basically, `mysite.com` and `downloads.mysite.com`. And, I want to put them both on the same load balancer and SSL certificate.

I know how to create the http(s) load balancer for the main site, using an instance group for the backend service and adding an SSL cert, but I can't seem to figure out how to add the downloads subdomain to that load balancer and cert.

I thought to create an additional bucket backend service for downloads. I'm not sure how to set the Host and Path Rules. I've tried:

```
Host                      Path                      Backend
----------------------------------------------------------------
All unmatched (default)   All unmatched (default)   main-backend
downloads.mysite.com      /*                        bucket-backend
```

And for the certificate, I tried using mysite.com & downloads.mysite.com, as well as [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) & downloads.mysite.com, but I always get the error FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE.

And then there's the DNS settings. In the case of just the main LAMP site, I would add an A record with the load balancer's IP address. Not sure if I need to add another A record for the downloads subdomain or not.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you configured your DNS?

Comment: I have an A record for mysite.com pointing to the load balancer, and a second A record for downloads.mysite.com pointing to the same load balancer. Also a CNAME  with www.mysite.com pointing to mysite.com.

Answer (score 0):

For your comment, you already have an A record pointing to your load balancer IP address for the downloads domain, that is enough in most cases but you can read [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting#domain-status) another reasons why you are getting a `FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE` error. Check that your  downloads domain is visible on internet, can you ping it successfully? It should respond with your LB IP address. Fix this first before you try again to create the additional certificate. Consider that there is a [project quota](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#ssl_certificates) for certificates, verify you are not reaching it.

You can create a global certificate for several domains using a

```
gcloud command like this example:
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create my-cert \
    --domains=one.com,two.com,www.three.com \
    --global
```

You can use URL Maps and combine them if needed with patch matchers in order to direct traffic for your different backends. You can read [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts) about these concepts, and [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map) you will find how to use them.